# I am trying to create a shortcut in Powershell from one server to another

Tags: powershell, new-item

```
$PrivateDrive = "Sharedrivepath1"
$ScanDrive = "ScanDrivePath2"

New-Item -Itemtype SymbolicLink -Path $PrivateDrive -Name ScanDrive -Value $ScanDrive
```

I am trying to create a shortcut from the ScanDrive to the PrivateDrive, I have a full filepath and have access to both locations.

These both exist.

But I get the error "New-Item : Symbolic Links are not supported for the specified path"

EDIT: This is how I declare my Private and Scan Drives

```
$SamaccountName = ($name).Givenname + '.' + ($name.Surname)
$PrivateDrive = '\\SERVER1\private\home folders\' + $SamaccountName
$ScanDrive = "\\SERVER2\Shares_2\" + $SamaccountName
```

Comment: Show us exactly how you define `$PrivateDrive` and `$ScanDrive`. In PowerShell version => 6.2, the target of the symbolic link can be a relative path. Prior to PowerShell v6.2, the target **must be a fully-qualified path**.

Comment: @Theo I Added it to the bottom, I cant figure out how to lay it out like normal in comments

Comment: Your path for `$PrivateDrive` has a space in it You need to use quotes around it when calling the `New-Item` cmdlet. BTW. Are you sure users SamAccountNames are in the form of `GivenName.Surname` ? A SamAccountname should be 20 characters or less..

Comment: @Theo it still gives me the same error, "New-Item : Symbolic Links are not supported for the specified path" and yes, that is the SamAccountName, thats the standard my location has set and am required to use.

Comment: Can you do it using mklink.exe from within a PowerShell console (run as admin)? `mklink /d "$PrivateDrive" "$ScanDrive"`. What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: I tried this, CMD opened up, but did nothing. @Theo

Answer (score 0):

The error message is PowerShell's, in response to the underlying [`CreateSymbolicLink()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinka) WinAPI function reporting error code `1` (`INVALID_FUNCTION`).

There are two possible causes that I'm aware of:

- A *configuration* problem: R2R (Remote-to-Remote) *symlink evaluation* is *disabled* (which is true by default.

  - To *query* the current configuration, run the following:

    ```sh
    fsutil behavior get SymLinkEvaluation
    ```
  - To *modify* the configuration, you must call from an *elevated* (run as admin) session. The following enables R2R symlink evaluation:

    ```sh
    # Requires an ELEVATED session.
    fsutil behavior set SymLinkEvaluation R2R:1
    ```
- (Less likely) A *fundamental* limitation:

  - The remote *link* path (the *target* path too?) is *not* exposed vie one of the following technologies, which are the ones listed as supported in [the linked WinAPI help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createsymboliclinka):

    - Server Message Block (SMB) 3.0 protocol
    - SMB 3.0 Transparent Failover (TFO)
    - Resilient File System (ReFS)

Comment: I tried changing the R2R syslink evaluation and it didn't change anything. I know you said its Less Likely, but how can I check these? @mklement0

Comment: @Fluffarmy223, unfortunately, I don't know - perhaps you can ask whoever administraters the networked drives.